# Place items in between of list using drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, drag-and-drop

I am making a drag and drop function using pure angular and typescript without any library.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="listArea">
    <h4> Drag and Drop list in Green Area: </h4>
    <ul class="unstyle">
        <li id="1" draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag($event)">
            i am list 1
        </li>
        <li id="2" draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag($event)">
            i am list 2
        </li>
        <li id="3" draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag($event)">
            i am list 3
        </li>
        <li id="4" draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag($event)">
            i am list 4
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="buildArea" id="div1" (drop)="drop($event)" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)">
    <h4> Drop Here </h4>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  }

  drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
  }
}
```

Working **Stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wyimor

In the above given example, i can able to drag and drop list items from one div to another.

Here i had used,

```
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
```

So its getting append to the last of previously dropped.
But i am in the need to drop the list items wherever user needs.

For eg, If the user drag drops the list order as,

```
I am list 1
I am list 2
I am list 4
I am list 5
```

Where user now drags the list `I am list 3` and needs to place in between `I am list 2` and `I am list 4`.

The dropped item should be a separate list without appending into `li`.

Kindly help to achieve drop the dragged list items in between of the dropped list items wherever user wants.

Comment: Your stackblitz is doing what you want!!! still what is the issue?

Comment: I had explained the scenario in the question itself, if user drops 1,2,4,5 and he forgot to add list 3, so he want to place it in between 2 and 4.. THis is my only requirement.. Did this working in my stackblitz?

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT he is asking for suffule inside green box

Comment: Yeah previously and just now I checked, it is working fine in the green box itself

Comment: @UnluckyAj, Yes you are right..

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT, If its working then why should i post this question.. Did u try drag and drop list items 1,3,4 in top to green box. ANd later if you try to drop list 2 it will go at the last after 4.. But i need to place it in between 1 and 3..

Comment: @UnluckyAj yeah shuffle is not working in the green box. I've dropped 3 over 2, then 3 comes between the 2 and 4, that's why I am saying it is working

Comment: I am surprised in your comment, as i am using, ```ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))```, it will get only append to last.

Comment: Try to drop 1, 2 and 4 and then drop 3 over 2, still it is coming between 2 and 4

Comment: Its not working, Two items (3,2) getting appends into one ```<li>``` tag.. If you again drag that dropped 3 then the list ```3,2``` comes along as one.. Thats not at all a working solution.. I should get the dropped list as single ```<li>```

Comment: very well. i would say they are similar tho. both questions insinuate that drag and drop is needed and an answer to either question will solve both.